# Starting Code from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()

int quantity = 0;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z;
double region[5][6];
int shipping = 20.00;
region[0][0] = 0;


for (x=0;x<5;x++) {

    for (y=0; y<6; y++) {
        z=x;
       if(y == 0)
       {region[x][y] = y + 1 + z;}
       else if(y == 1)
       {region[x][y] =  region[x][y-1] * 2;}
           else if(y == 2)
           {region[x][y] = region[x][y-1]  + .50;}
               else if(y == 3)
                   {region[x][y] = region[x][y-1] + .50;}
                   else if(y == 4)
                   {region[x][y] = region[x][y-1] + .250;}
                       else 
                       {region[x][y] = region[x][y-1] + .250;}
    }

}
cout<<"Please input the region"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Enter quantity"<<endl;
cin>>quantity;
if (quantity > 6)
{b = 5;}
else
{b = quantity;}

cout<<"The price of shipping comes out to: "<<region[a][b] + shipping<<" Since $20 is added for the shipping cost"<<endl;

return 0 ;
```

}

So right now I have to type 0,0 for region and quantity to get the first cell. But since I am starting at region 1 and quantity 1, I was to make the user input 1,1. How will I go about doing this with C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user has entered the region validate that all values are greater than 0. If they are subtract one from them and process the data just like you are now.

```
if(a < 1) a = 1;
if(quantity < 1) quantity = 1;

// Subtract 1 from the values
a--;
quantity--;

if (quantity > 6)
{b = 5;}
else
{b = quantity;}
cout<<"The price of shipping comes out to: "<<region[a][b] + shipping<<" Since $20 is added for the shipping cost"<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about substracting 1 to each value ?

```
cout<<"Please input the region"<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"Enter quantity"<<endl;
cin>>quantity;

--a;
--quantity;
```